# How to get the audio recording feature working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder

I am trying to add a voice recording feature to my react app, but it's not working as I thought it would. I did a console.log() on the ondataavailable method and got something, a continously growing array of 'blobs' every second, but when I tried a console.log() in the onstop method I did not get anthing.

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream) => {
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)

  const audio = document.querySelector('audio')
  const microphoneBtn = document.querySelector('.microphone-btn')
  microphoneBtn?.addEventListener('click', function () {
    mediaRecorder.start(1000)
    setRecordingState(mediaRecorder.state)
  })
  //start recording
  let chunks = []
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = e => {
    chunks.push(e.data)
  }

  console.log(chunks)

  //stop recording
  const stopBtn = document.querySelector('.stop-audio-recording')
  stopBtn?.addEventListener('click', function () {
    mediaRecorder.stop()
    setRecordingState(mediaRecorder.state)
  })
  mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', e => {
    console.log(chunks)
    const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" })
    chunks = []

    const audioUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    audio.src = audioUrl
  })
  mediaRecorder.onstop = e => {
    console.log(chunks)
    const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" })
    chunks = []

    const audioUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    audio.src = audioUrl
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet provided above registers two `'stop'` event listeners. One by calling `addEventListener()` and another one by assigning it to `onstop`. I guess removing one of them will fix the problem.

The browser invokes both event listeners directly after each other. The first one is probably doing what you expect it to do. But it will also clear the `chunks`. By the time the second event listener gets executed `chunks` is an empty array. It will turn it into an empty `Blob` and ultimately assign it to the `src` of the audio element.